# Getting error in implementing the embedded login on the Heroku app

Tags: login, heroku, login-errors, identity, embedded-services

I have created this Heroku app - https://embedded-login-rahul.herokuapp.com/ following this document- https://github.com/salesforceidentity/embedded-login-example for implementing the embedded login.

For this, I have created a connected app and a Heroku app and configured the environmental variables on the Heroku app. But I am getting the below errors on the app:-

[image]

However, I am able to successfully authenticate the user from Salesforce. But getting the below error with the IFrame:-

[image]

```
My connected app configurations are as below:-
```

[image]

```
My Heroku app environmental variables are as below:-
```

[image]

I am not sure what's going wrong with the configurations. Any thoughts on what can be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my issue is resolved and I am able to successfully login using Embedded Login. In my case, I have to make 2 changes to make it work.

1. Change the "Login Page Type" of the Community from "Experience Builder Page" to "Default Page"
   [image]
2. For the *"X-Frame-Options"* issue, I have to set the environmental variable *SALESFORCE_MASK_REDIRECTS* to *true* on the Heroku app.

I am still getting the *"Uncaught Syntax Error"* as shown in the question. However, the login is working file even with it.